# How to make text appear after slide in image transition on hover

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make header text and body text appear (fade in) under the right side of an image that slides in after the mouse hovers over it.

I am currently using this code I have found and it gives me the effect on the image I want but I don't know how to add in the text.

Here is a link to where I found the image effect if you'd like to see it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/13753/

When you mouse over the black square it extends and under the right side is where I want the text to go.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
**HTML:**

<a href="">
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100- 4.jpg" />
</div>
</a>

**CSS:**

    .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 0px solid black;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -300px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: .5s;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: You should vote on an answer or change the details of your question if the answer wasn’t what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class='slide'></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class='slide'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 0px solid black;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -300px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    transition: 1s;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper:hover .slide {
    transition: .5s;
    left: 0;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.slide').on('mouseenter', function () {
$('.inner_text').remove();
$(this).append("<a class='inner_text'>HELLO THERE</a>")
})
```

**RESULT**

[image]

****** * * * * * * EDIT * * * * * * ********

If you want to have the **text outside the black boxes**, filling the space where the non-hovered box is, just change your jQuery to:

```
$('.slide').eq(0).on('mouseenter', function () {
$('.inner_text').remove();
$(this).parent().parent().append("<a class='inner_text'>HELLO THERE</a>")
$('.inner_text').css('margin-left', '290px')
$('.inner_text').css('margin-top', '-98px')
$('.inner_text').css('position', 'fixed')
})

$('.slide').eq(1).on('mouseenter', function () {
$('.inner_text').remove();
$(this).parent().parent().append("<a class='inner_text'>HELLO THERE</a>")
$('.inner_text').css('margin-left', '290px')
$('.inner_text').css('margin-top', '-120px')
$('.inner_text').css('position', 'fixed')
})

$('.slide').on('mouseleave', function () {
$('.inner_text').remove();
})
```

**RESULT**:

[image]

You can **adjust the positioning of the text** if it's not sitting where you want.

Comment: This is great, thanks, but is there a way to make the "hello there" text appear underneath the top black box after it slides out (in the white space where the lower black box slides in) instead of situating it on the left over the black box?